# React Router creating a Route with a path defined by an API array of objects blocked by React Query

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-query

I am  using React-Query besides React-Router and I can not extract the data with React-Query in App.jsx.

```
function App() {
  const { isLoading, software } = useSoftware();

  return (
    <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
      <ReactQueryDevtools initialIsOpen={false} />
      <BrowserRouter>
        <GlobalStyles />
        <Routes>
          <Route element={<AppLayout />}>
            <Route index element={<MainPage replace to="home" />} />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </QueryClientProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

`const { isLoading, software } = useSoftware();` this is a custom hook that fetches data from a supabase table, but in `App.jsx` it renders the following error:

> No QueryClient set, use QueryClientProvider to set one.

Normally in other files it works.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can create routes programmatically based on the properties of objects in React, particularly if you're using a library like React Router. You can use the map function to iterate over your data and generate  components dynamically. Here's an example of how you can do this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

const data = [
  { name: 'product1', component: Product1 },
  { name: 'product2', component: Product2 },
  // Add more products here
];

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        {data.map((item) => (
          <Route key={item.name} path={`/${item.name}`}>
            <item.component />
          </Route>
        ))}
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}

function Product1() {
  return <div>Product 1 Page</div>;
}

function Product2() {
  return <div>Product 2 Page</div>;
}

export default App;
```

This way, you can programmatically create routes based on the name property of each object in your data array. Make sure to adjust the data array and components to match your specific use case.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use React hooks that access a context from higher in the ReactTree than where the context provider is rendered and provides the context. In this case the component using the custom `useSoftware` hook needs to have the `QueryClientProvider` component rendered above it in the ReactTree.

Move `QueryClientProvider` from `App` to wrap `App`.

Example:

```
function App() {
 const { isLoading, software } = useSoftware();

 return (
   <BrowserRouter>
     <Routes>
       <Route element={<AppLayout />}>
         <Route index element={<MainPage replace to="home" />} />
     </Routes>
   </BrowserRouter>
 );
}

const WrappedApp = () => (
  <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
    <ReactQueryDevtools initialIsOpen={false} />
    <GlobalStyles />
    <App />
  </QueryClientProvider>
);

export default WrappedApp;
```